# How to prevent login blocks for Android app review team

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I have built an application for Android that needs a Google account to function. The app-review team uses a Gmail account I created for it, and I have provided credentials.
But what I try, Google keeps preventing a login (Google has blocked suspicious login), because the login seems to be from India.

How can I unblock this? Because every time the review failes, and it takes me a few new days to re-submit the app. I am quite confused, how can I provide a proper login for the team?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you solve this?

Comment: Creating a workspace account :/